Why doesn't the rotation of a inertia tensor by a rotation matrix cancel itself out?
I'm currently reading about rotating an inertia tensor by a rotation matrix. I've found this formula for the rotation:
$I'=RIR^T$
Where R is the rotation matrix and I is the inertia tensor.
I can't see how this should work.As the transformed rotation matrix is the same as the inverted matrix. The multiplication of the tensor with the inverse matrix and then the matrix should cancel each other and leave us with the same tensor as before.
Is there something that I've missed? Is matrix-tensor multiplication different from matrix-matrix multiplication?

Because the matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Matrices don't generally commute.  Generally speaking, $RI \neq IR$ and $IR^T \neq R^TI$ for $I$ the inertia tensor and $R$ a rotation matrix.  You'd need at least one of those to be true in order to cancel terms like you suggest in your question.
